# Communication using CC2520

Tags: communication, msp430

> My team has been trying to send data through a CC2520 using a
>   MSPEXP430F5438 board. We tried using the FIFO_READ and FIFO_WRITE
>   command but it was of no avail. We also tried using the RAM_READ and
>   RAM_WRITE command but still the results were the same. We checked the
>   interfacing of MSP430 and CC2520 and that seems fine. Could anyone
>   suggest some way to find out where our problem lies(sender/reciever)?
>
> Regards, Pratyush

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, the CC2520 is a SPI-controlled state machine. This means that the radio transceiver requires a particular sequence of commands to transmit or receive data.

I would recommend taking a look at Section 21 (page 85, when written) within the [CC2520 Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cc2520). Additionally, Section 19 and 20 shows the TX and RX procedure, respectively.

[SmartRF Studio](http://www.ti.com/tool/smartrftm-studio) is often the easiest way to get started, as it has a full GUI interface to the radio. However, you may need to purchase the [CC2520 dev kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2520dk) or have a supported baseboard for the CC2520. I believe the [MSP-EXP430F5438 board](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430f5438) does not support SmartRF Studio, but I could not easily find the answer. I know SmartRF studio recognizes the MSP-EXP430F5438 when you launch the software, but I'm not sure the software can use the MSP-EXP430F5438 as a baseboard for the desktop GUI control of the radio.

If you want to program a "hello world" onto your MSP-EXP430F5438 and CC2520, I recommend using TI's provided [sample code](http://www.ti.com/litv/zip/swrc090b) for the CC2520, and perusing the [CC2520 page](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2520).

For TI's CCxxxx radios, in C pseudo-code, to transmit/send a message you might do the following:

```
SPI_Strobe(IDLE); /* Reset radio state machine to 'start' state (IDLE) */
SPI_WriteBurstReg(TXFIFO, tx_data, tx_data_length); /* Write data to TX FIFO */
SPI_Strobe(TX);   /* Start radio transmission */

_BIS(LPM3+GIE); /* While TX finishes, sleep MCU with general interrupt enable */
                /* Use GPIO to interrupt. When TX is finished, RETI from ISR */
                /*     and continue to next line */

SPI_Strobe(FLUSH_TXFIFO); /* Flush TX buffer (optional) */
SPI_Strobe(IDLE);         /* Reset radio state machine to 'start' state (IDLE)
                          /*     Can auto enter IDLE when TX done - see doc. */
SPI_Strobe(PWR_DOWN);     /* Turn off radio to save power (optional) */
```

Above, I'm using all-caps to indicate a static address/byte definition from a header file.